# Operate multiple devices using ADB commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, adb

I'd like to assign the output of adb to multiple variables so multiple devices can be controlled at once.

```
 adb devices
```

then CMD will display

List of devices attached
xxyyzz       device
aabbccdd     device

I'd like to assign xxyyzz to a and aabbccdd to b.
I managed to do it for one device but not multiple using the following code:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`adb devices`) DO (
SET SN=%%F
)
set SN=%SN: =%
set SN=%SN:device=%
echo %SN%
pause
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any benefit in setting an unknown number of connected devices to single letter variables, if you don't know how many were returned a connected, you'll have no idea which veribles are defined.

That said, the following code should perform the exact task you outlined in your question:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=96"&For /F Skip^=1 %%G In ('adb.exe devices 2^>NUL')Do Set /A i+=1&cmd.exe /C "Exit /B !i!"&Set "!=ExitCodeASCII!=%%G"
```

If, due to the reason I mentioned upon opening, you now need visual confirmation of the devices you have defined, you could probably expand the code like this:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=96"&For /F Skip^=1 %%G In ('adb.exe devices 2^>NUL')Do Set /A i+=1&cmd.exe /C Exit /B !i!&Set "!=ExitCodeASCII!=%%G"
If %i% Lss 97 GoTo :EOF
Set /A i-=96&Set "letters=0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"&Echo You have !i! devices
(For /L %%G In (1,1,%i%)Do For /F %%H In ("!letters:~%%G,1!")Do Echo %%%%H%% = !%%H!)&Pause
```